# why the refcount is 1 when i use debug_zval_dump() ? PHP

Tags: php

I can't  comprehend the refcount that debug_zval_dump() print.

```
<?php
    $str = "test function";
    $sr1 = '';
    $str1 = & $str;

    debug_zval_dump($str);
```

The output of the above code: string(13) "test function" refcount(1)

when i delete the ampersand before the $str:

```
<?php
    $str = "test function";
    $sr1 = '';
    $str1 =  $str;

    debug_zval_dump($str);
```

The output of the above code :string(13) "test function" refcount(3)

what has happened ?  The first refcount is "1".But, i think it also referenced three times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the refcount is 2 not 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221645/why-the-refcount-is-2-not-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a copy of $str is being made, when the function is called.